# Concurrent downloading and uploading brings length error (.Net to FTP).

Tags: .net, ftp

I have a ftp server act as public file repository. A-app can upload file to the server and B-app can download file from the server. If B-app try to download the file which one be uploading by A-app ,file length would be incorrect.
I wanna lock the file which be uploading to block downloading apps before uploading completed. Anyone can help me?

I'm developing on .NetFramework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're writing both applications, you can do it any way you want.

You can have the upload application write files into a staging area and only move them into the area the download application accesses when it's done. You can create a shared table of locked files stored in a text file. You can use your platform's file locking.

You can do it however you want -- just code what you want.

Answer (score 0):

In your server, when a file is being uploaded, you can create the file stream as such:

```
FileStream localFile = new FileStream(Path, FileMode.Create, FileShare.None)
```

The term `FileShare.None` will prevent anything else, including your sofware, from opening the file until `localFile.Close()` or `localFile.Dispose()` is called.  If someone tries to download the file before it's closed, an exception will be thrown.

Comment: It's depressed that upload app can be various - ThirdParty Client or Someone's service for example. I can only control my download app. I want to have the download app check modified date of file, is it viable?